# Refine gem's class method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, refinements

I have to wrap some behavior around an external gem in a elegant and isolated manner. Given the abstraction below, everything runs smoothly, but  'bar' is never printed.
Could someone tell me why?

## My code:

```
module RefineGem
  refine GemMainModule::GemClass do
    def self.foo
      p 'bar'
      super
    end
  end
end

module Test
  using RefineGem

  def test
    GemMainModule::GemClass.foo
  end
end

class Testing
  include Test
end

Testing.new.test
```

## Gem code:

```
module GemMainModule
  class Base
    include GemMainModule::Fooable
  end

  class GemClass < Base
  end
end

module GemMainModule
  module Fooable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    class_methods do
      def foo
        p 'zoo'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I never used `refinements` since prepending modules is way cleaner, robust and intelligent approach; but I would suggest you to `refine GemMainModule::GemClass.singleton_class { def foo ... end }`. I doubt refinements work for class methods.

Comment: By all means then post your solution using modules as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: What do you mean “using models”?

Comment: it was a typo, I meant modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt refinements work for class methods. You might refine the `singleton_class` though:

```
module RefineGem
  refine GemMainModule::GemClass.singleton_class do
    def foo
      p 'bar'
      super
    end
  end
end
```

---

I personally prefer to use [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-prepend) to achieve the same functionality:

```
GemMainModule::GemClass.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
  def foo
    p 'bar'
    super
  end
end)
```

Comment: I like this and it works, if I may be annoying and raise just one missing point for my situation: can I control the scope of usage? (like refinements do with the "using" keyword), I want the behavior to be overridden in a particular place and nowhere else.

Comment: No, with `Module#prepend` you can not do that. Honestly, I never ever felt a necessity to deal with usage scopes. Even more: it sounds counterintuitive and more error-prone to me, that here `foo` works this way and there it works that way.